# Python DateTime TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Period' with type 'str'

Tags: python, datetime

I'm converting a Date to a datetime64ns, then converting that to just Year and Month using to_period.

Here is my code:

```
df['the_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['the_Date'])

df['month_year'] = df.the_Date.dt.to_period('M')
```

Then I'm looking to assign a value to each period, but I receive the error:

```
df.loc[df['month_year'] == '2017-10', 'assigned_period'] = 1

TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Period' with type 'str'
```

Comment: You are comparing them right here: df['month_year'] == '2017-10' (comparing period with string)

Comment: @ddalu5 - that is where I'm receiving the error

Comment: It's not an error, you are converting it to a period here: df['month_year'] = df.the_Date.dt.to_period('M')

Then you are comparing that period with a string '2017-10', which you can't do

Answer (score 1):

Solved it this way:

```
df.loc[req_df['month_year'] == ((pd.to_datetime('2017-10')).to_period('M')), 'assigned_period'] = 1
```